# What type of Visual Studio c++ project should i select for making basic unix apps

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Im in a computer science 1 class and we are programing using C++. In class we use emacs on unix servers. We can also use visual studio if we want. If its going to be graded in emacs and run there by the professor what type of project should i pick in Visual studio for the best results.

every time i try to compile the code i get these errors

```
Warning 1   warning C4627: '#include <iostream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use   c:\Users\Sam\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Test 3\Test 3\Test 3.cpp 3   1   Test 3
Error   2   error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?   c:\Users\Sam\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Test 3\Test 3\Test 3.cpp 16  1   Test 3
```

here is the code:

```
// Samuel LaManna

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Hello World!";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    return 0:
}
```

Comment: drive by down voter: please leave comments why you have down voted!

Comment: Im new to this site, did i mess up something?

Comment: did you mean to say "visual basic" not "visual studio" in the question? maybe that's why you got a down vote? - which would be rough

Comment: @Sam no you did not mess anything up. Someone down voted your question and all four answers without adding a comment indicating why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest you just use emacs and unix.  Ubuntu Linux is free, emacs is free, and g++ is free (c++ compiler).  It's best to always use the same platform your professors are using.  If you *have* to use Visual Studio for some reason, you can do a console application project, but you are going to have all kinds of trouble doing it that way.  Just use emacs/unix.

Comment: To me it seems like Visual Studio keeps everything cleaner. Its color coded, it auto indents, etc. Emacs is just a console window. white text on a black background

Comment: Visual Studio is an excellent IDE, but emacs is actually more powerful and better suited for academic unix development.

Comment: @Sam - Emacs can be run as a normal window program (outside of the console). It can also do syntax highlighting, automatic code indentation, and many of the other features of Visual Studio as well. See http://dev.pocoo.org/~gbrandl/emacs2.png as an example.

Comment: Ok thanks, so you dont think that all of Visual Studios fancy color-coding and other stuff will help that much?

Comment: Emacs :) Run on X-Windows in Linux. You can also get a Windows version if you're developing in Windows. As others have mentioned, I would recommend learning on Linux though.

Comment: Ok thanks, i am thinking of running Linux in a vm. what flavor of linux should i use. performance isnt an issue Does this program just connect to the unix server and just display things nicer? or is it an app.

Comment: What do people in the industry use. i want to learn the system i plan on using after college.

Comment: Try ubuntu linux.  It's free, easy to install, and very a solid distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Select an empty project, or a console project. Make sure you're not using any Windows API.

Answer (score 2):

A "Windows Console Project". And go in the project preferences and turn off "Use Precompiled Headers."

Answer (score 1):

Add your include `#include <iostream>` after the `#include "stdafx.h"` line. If you don't have  this line add it as first line or disable the precompiled headers.

To disable precompiled headers:

Go to properties on your project, then C/C++, Precompiled Header and then Precompiled Headers - Don't use precompiled headers.

Comment: No, it won't. Disable precompiled headers, as suggested.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with `stdafx.h`. In fact, I wouldn't use precompiled headers at all, for simplicity's sake. Remember, the marker doesn't use the same environment as you do.

Answer (score -3):

the simple fact that the $600 commercial product doesn't include "Linux C++ makefile project" in the "new project" menu should be reason enough not to use it. Consumers don't want to pay for products that can do *less*.

Comment: Why would one bother with emacs then?  They can't even open a simple MSVC makefile project!  Or _any_ MSVC project.  Free is nice, but not when it does so much _less_.

Comment: That would be a good rebuttal Mooing Duck, but the fact that things like emacs run on any OS while Visual Studio is locked to Windows means Visual Studio is by default more limiting regardless of its feature set because you have to pay Microsoft twice to use it.

Comment: If you can't find the no-cost (and completely legal) version of Visual C++, you're not going to do well as a computer programmer.  And to students, the fancy versions are also available at no cost, though that's a little trickier to discover (keyword: DreamSpark).